# Fastest way to check whether a single element in common exists between two enumerables

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a method I'm writing where I want to be able to filter orders based on whether they have one or more ordered products in them that exist in the selection of products made by the user. Currently I'm doing this with:

```
SelectedProductIDs.Intersect(orderProductIDs).Any()
```

executed on each order (~20,000 orders total in the database and expected to grow quickly), where both SelectedProducts and orderProductIDs are string[]. I've also attempted to use pre-generated HashSets for both SelectedProductIDs and orderProductIDs, but this made no appreciable difference in the speed of comparison.

However, both of these are unpleasantly slow - ~300ms per selection change - particularly given that the dates made available to the sliders within the UI are predicated entirely on the results of this query, so user interaction has to halt in some fashion. Is there a (very) significantly faster way to do this?

Edit: May not have been clear enough - order objects are materialized from SQL data at launch-time and these queries are performed later, in a secondary window of the overall application. SQL is irrelevant to the specifics of this question; this is a LINQ-to-Objects question.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar He's materialized the results of the db table into an in memory collection anyway, so that shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: Have you an index on OrderProductId Table column ? The database are SQL Server ?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar, Max, Servy's right - all the SQL queries have already been made and all the data has been loaded into custom objects. This is a question specifically related to C# and to LINQ-to-Objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LINQ intersect is going to reconstruct a new `HashSet` based on the input value no matter what you do, even if the input is already a `HashSet`.  Its implementation mutates the hash set internally (which is how it avoids yielding duplicate values) so it is important to make a copy of the input sequence, even if it's already a `HashSet`.

You can create your own `Intersect` method that accepts a hashset, instead of populating a new one.  To avoid mutating it though, you'll have to settle for a bag-based `Intersect`, rather than a set based `Intersect` (i.e., duplicates in the sequence will all be yielded).  Clearly that's not a problem in your case:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> IntersectAll<T>(
    this HashSet<T> set, IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    foreach (var item in sequence)
        if (set.Contains(item))
            yield return item;
}
```

Now you can write:

```
SelectedProductIDs.InsersectAll(orderProductIDs).Any();
```

And the hashset won't need to be re-constructed each time.

Comment: Feeling a little dumb here, but when I'm using IntersectAll as HashSet<string>.IntersectAll(ItemIDs), the compiler is telling me there's no definition for "IntersectAll", and no extension method accepting a first argument of type Hashset<string>. I'm pretty new to generic extension methods so this is slightly obscure to me.

Comment: Got it, the compiler for some reason wasn't letting me know the extension had to be in a static class. This is great - about 4x-5x improvement speed-wise.

Comment: @furkle You should have gotten a warning when compiling the extension method, in addition to the error where you were trying to call it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know whether it's VS2012 Express or my installation of VS2012 Express, but on certain occasions I just miss a compiler error or two until a few rebuilds later.

Comment: @furkle Most people focus on the errors before looking at warnings, despite the fact that in this case the warning is the underlying cause of the error.

Comment: Hm, odd: "Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class" (when it finally showed up) shows up for me as an error, not a warning.

Comment: @furkle Okay, it's not a warning, but an error.  Was going from memory.

Comment: I think there might be a typo above - shouldn't it be if (set.Contains(item)) yield return item, and not if (sequence.Contains(item))? As it stands, it looks like sequence is querying itself for the existence of its own members, which would result in IntersectAll<T>.Any() always returning true.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are reading all the values from the database into memory and then querying. If you instead use LINQ to EF, it will translate the LINQ query into a SQL query that gets run on the database, which could be significantly faster.

Comment: He's (appears to be) materializing the query into in-memory object before he needs to do any work; when initializing the whole UI.  He is then acting on those in memory objects later one when speed is important.  That is the proper way to design this.

Comment: @Servy, Yes, you're correct, the orders are encapsulated into an Order object immediately after the database is queried. Perhaps I should've specifically mentioned LINQ-to-Objects.